# Why are my static images re-downloaded?

Tags: javascript

Whenever I hit the reload button in FireFox w/ the console open, I can see that images are re-downloaded.

I would have thought they would have been cached on the first download.

What controls the caching?

Is there a way to make it such that they are only ever downloaded once using JavaScript?

Looking at other sites, this seems to be normal.  But why is this, I thought the browser would be smart enough to cache images which do not change.

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have code running on a server, for example apache/php, the php engine takes care of the "cache control" and "expires" headers for the generated page. You can use code or modify php.ini to change the default behaviour.

Static files are shared directly by the web server (apache). Caching is done by apache and the only way to change the defaults is to modify apache's configuration files.

Normaly if the browser requests an already downloaded file the server will respond with 304 "Not modified".

My best guess is that your web server is not configured correctly or your files have modification times in the future (this could happen if you moved files from other computers/filesystems/timezones).

Comment: How does the server know if it was already downloaded?  Is it simply based on file name?

Answer (score 2):

You can suggest that resources such as images are cached using appropriate [cache control](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) and/or [expires](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) headers. But clicking the reload/refresh buttons in browsers *may* re-download them regardless.